# Mysql doing crash on IIS application

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed mysql only to one employ use WordPress, and now I am getting this error on one of my main project, and I never used mysql, ONLY SQL server.

When I Unnistall all mysql, the project back to work normally.

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> #### *Configuration Error*
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.  Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> ```
> Line 250:       <providers>
> Line 251:         <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" 
> Line 252:         <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
> Line 253:       </providers>
> Line 254:     </membership>
> ```
>
> **Source File:** C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config **Line:** 252
>
> **Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.
>
> ```
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version: 4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.18044

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of **text error messages**. This is extremely irritating, especially as your screenshot here is unreadable.

Comment: @tadman: Not *that* unreadable...

Comment: @eggyal It's looking a lot better now. The original screenshot was crushed down in size, the text just a smudge.

Comment: @tadman: My point was, I converted it from said screenshot into its current form.  So it can't have been *that* unreadable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the MySql installer, mysql-installer-community-5.6.14.0.exe, I removed Connector/Net 6.7.4. That removed all MySql references from machine.config and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error just when you are creating a new project and dont yet have mysql set up, just go to the location of machine.config(make a backup copy of original).Now tweak machine.config to comment out the mysql parts referred to in the error trace. Try running again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I Just had that issue, I instaled MySQL Connectors before and the only thing I did to solve the issue was to add the MySql Reference to the project and that was it.